# variable is undefined in else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am confused as to why I am getting an 'undefined' error in my code. I am trying to delete an id from an array using the variable of 'id', but it errors with 'undefined'. I have tried various options of moving the 'var id;' but still I get the error. I have marked in the code where the error is occuring and would be grateful if someone could help me to correct this error. Many thanks

```
$(function() {
  info = [];
  $(document).on('click', '.rowChk', function() {
    var id;
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#rowClk').show();
      var currentRows = $(this).closest("tr");
      var rackid = currentRows.find("td:eq(0)").text();
      //    var rackidnumber = currentRows.find("td:eq(1)").html();
      var rackservice = currentRows.find("td:eq(2)").html();
      var rackactivity = currentRows.find("td:eq(3)").html();
      var rackdept = currentRows.find("td:eq(4)").html();
      var rackcompany = currentRows.find("td:eq(5)").html();
      var rackaddress = currentRows.find("td:eq(6)").html();
      var rackuser = currentRows.find("td:eq(7)").html();
      var rackitem = currentRows.find("td:eq(8)").html();
      var rackddate = currentRows.find("td:eq(9)").html();
      var rackdate = currentRows.find("td:eq(10)").html();

      id = rackid;

      data = {};
      data.rackids = id;
      //    data.idnumber = rackidnumber;
      data.service = rackservice;
      data.activity = rackactivity;
      data.dept = rackdept;
      data.company = rackcompany;
      data.address = rackaddress;
      data.user = rackuser;
      data.item = rackitem;
      data.intakedate = rackdate;
      data.destroydate = rackddate;
      info.push(data);
    } else {
      console.log(id); <--- Showing as undefined
      var index = info.findIndex(function(item) {
        return item.id === id;
      });
      if (index !== -1) {
        info.splice(index, 1);
        if (info.length === 0) {
          $('#rowClk').css('display', 'none');
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML also

Comment: well of course, because if you go down to the `else` then it has never been defined with a value. before your if statement you use  `var id;` but never assign it a value.

Comment: ^^ "ofc" means "of course" (not everyone knows all of these abbreviations, particularly people with English as a second language).

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal what does HTML have to do with this problem ? . The problem, as @Carsten mentioned above, is that the `id` doesn't have any value declared in the else statement or outside the if conditional. It's value is declared only if the condition is passed. If the condition is not ( returns false ), it goes into the `else` statement where the `id` is undefined.

Comment: When you have an `if` statement that has an `else` you get **one or the other**, so when the `if` body gets executed, the `else` doesn't and vice versa.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal really? It's nothing to do with HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The value is undefined because you never assign a value to it when the code reaches the `else` statement.

You declare it `var id;` Then you open `if` statement where you assign the value and in the `else` it is just undefined.

You need to do this `id = rackid;` before the if else statement.

Comment: Thank you for reply. However, it is still showing as 'undefined'. Thanks

Comment: To complete, the correct assign will be: `var id= currentRows.find("td:eq(0)").text();`

Comment: @Greedo That shows as undefined. Do i need to replace `var rackid = currentRows.find("td:eq(0)").text();`

Comment: @user1532468 you wight i missed a piece: `var id= $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();`

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `id` has not been defined in the `else` flux. In order to help you understand, the else flux is equivalent to:

```
$(function() {
   info = [];
   $(document).on('click', '.rowChk', function() {
     var id;
     if (this.checked) {

     } else {
       console.log(id); <--- Showing as undefined
       var index = info.findIndex(function(item) {
           return item.id === id;
       });
       if (index !== -1) {
          info.splice(index, 1);
          if (info.length === 0) {
             $('#rowClk').css('display', 'none');
          }
       }
     }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Sorry Greedo but what is different in your code markup than mine? Thanks

Comment: Greedo is explaining why the problem occurs - your code is `var id; console.log(id)` - which is meaningless

Comment: @user1532468 you declare the `id` variable, but then never assign a value, and then print it. The value will be `undefined`.